# When I pop, i get "pointer being freed was not allocated" error

Tags: c++, vector

Here's the little piece of code that I have a problem with.
The anagram function returns a correct result (a vector of vectors of strings with the anagrams). This vector is full of correct anagrams except for the last element that is empty. I therefore try to pop it but I always get a "pointer being freed was not allocated" error. =/

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Dictionary d = create_dictionary("dico.txt");
    vector<vector<string> > v = anagrams("object", d, 0);

    v.pop_back(); //Error here

    return 0; 
}
```

When it comes to the "v.pop_back();" line, there's the error: "malloc: *** error for object 0x3000000000003: pointer being freed was not allocated".

I wanted to post the state of the memory just before pop_back but I can't post images because it's my first question but here's the content of v just before pop_back:

```
v = {
    [0] {
         [0] "cob"
         [1] "jet"
        }
    [1] {
         [0] "object"
        }
    [2] { }
}
```

I have looked everywhere I could and I didn't find anything =/
Does anyone know where it comes from? Thank you for your time ;)

Here's how I create my dictionary:

```
Dictionary create_dictionary(const string& filename) {
    Dictionary d;

    //Read the file and store the words in d.words
    ifstream file(filename.c_str());

    string word;

    if(file.is_open()) {
        while (!file.eof()) {
            file >> word;
            d.words.push_back(word);
        }
    }

    else
        cout << "There is a problem with the file !" << endl;

    file.close();
    return d; }
```

Comment: If you're on Linux, try valgrind.

Comment: It comes from your code. `Dictionary`, `create_dictionaty` and/or `anagrams`

Comment: Can you post your own implementations? Starting with `anagrams`

Comment: What does "dico.txt" contain? What would you expect to be inside of `v`? Would you mind to share the **relevant** part of your code?

Comment: This bug might be related to the "bad last element" bug. You need to post `anagrams` and probably the dictionary code, too. Most likely there is something undefined going on in there. (BTW: fixing a bug is a much better idea than trying to work around it - you shouldn't "touch up" results afterwards if they're wrong.)

Comment: The anagrams function uses the words of the dictionary file to find
all the unique combinations of words that use the same letters as the input string.
The dictionary file contains one word per line.

Comment: You should write `while (file >> word)`. Using `eof` is wrong. (But it's probably not the cause of the problem.)

Comment: Can you also post `anagrams`?

Comment: Now let's see `removeSpaces` :)

Comment: @molbdnilo Just corrected it, the problem's still there but thanks ;)

Comment: And also `getRidOfIn`

Comment: (My guess is that somewhere a `string` gets corrupted)

Comment: removeSpaces just returns its input.erase(remove_if(ret.begin(), ret.end(), ::isspace), ret.end()); ;-)

Comment: @molbdnilo: It could be.

Comment: @Bert.e try changing your removeSpaces to `input.erase(remove_if(ret.begin(), ret.end(), ::isspace))` without the last `ret.end()`

Comment: @YamMarcovic the result is the same and there still the error at the pop_back.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: In `anagramsHelper`, check `depth->size()` is greater than 0 before doing `(*depth).pop_back()`.

Comment: @YamMarcovic You just solved my problem, thank you very much :)
I'm not sure how to mark you answer as "the one" ^^ but Thanks ;)

Comment: The answer provided here comes close, plus I also commented there. You can accept that one and mark the question as closed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call pop_back if v is not empty, like:

```
if (!v.empty())
  v.pop_back();
```

Comment: Yep, specifically in the last one in `anagramsHelper`.